# Mock BatchRequestContent

Tags: .net, mocking, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to mock `BatchRequestContent` in .NET Graph v5 using `Moq`.

I have the following code:

```
var batchRequestContentCollection = new BatchRequestContentCollection(client);

var request = client.Users.Me.Messages[mailId].Content.ToGetRequestInformation();
await batchRequestContentCollection.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(request);

var response = await client.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContentCollection, cancellationToken);

var mailStream = await response.GetResponseStreamByIdAsync(request.Key);
```

So far I am able to mock the steps until `AddBatchRequestStepAsync(request)` like this:

```
mockRequestAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.ConvertToNativeRequestAsync<HttpRequestMessage>(
    It.IsAny<RequestInformation>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((RequestInformation requestInformation, CancellationToken token) =>
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var mailId = (string)requestInformation.PathParameters["message%2Did"];
        message.Content = new StringContent(mailId);
        return message;
    });
```

However I have troubles mocking the call from `client.Batch.PostAsync`.
How can I mock this call correctly?